# Step by step guide to setup display resolutions in xorg

Tags: xorg, drivers, display-settings

The default xorg configuration file created does not allow me to set up the display resolution I want (1360x768).

The auto configuration command `xorg -configure` didn't create the proper configuration file either (see below).

What's steps do I need to follow in order to manually add the resultion I want as one of the available ones?

Update:

I'm running this:

- CentOS 5.5, Linux 2.6.18-53.el5
- X Window System Version 7.1.1
- Gnome version 2.16

Auto-configuration:

- The same hardware with other linux distribution worked fine right after installation, allowing me to set up the display to 1600x900.
- The xorg.config file created during the installation allows me to set only 800x600 and 1024x768.
- If I raun `xorg -configure`, then X server won't start (it says that it could not be started with that configuration file). I had to manually go back to the previous xorg.config file.

Comment: This depends on the distribution you are using and the xorg it ships. Could you add these informations?

Comment: It's also hard to know what's wrong with your `xorg.conf` unless you at least tell us why it's not proper or, better yet, show us.

Comment: gvkv: I know nothing about xorg.conf, how should I know what part of it is not proper? :)

Comment: How do you know that `xorg -configure` "didn't create the proper configuration file"?

Comment: Can you start X?  What resolutions do you have available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use "xrandr" command for setting up resolution and multiple displays. Currently xorg.conf is on it's way to death, more and more Linux distributions rely on xrandr and they tend to ignore xorg.conf.

PS: Just to be clear, this means you use xrander to set up different stuff for your display, but you will still use the same X.org server.

PPS: Ah ... and you use xrandr on the fly, after you have xorg started and you have a graphical interface. Changes are applied immediately, but they are not saved, so if yo screw up something a restart fixes you problem. After you are finished with your setup, just put all the xrandr commands into a file, make it executable, and add it to your DE's startup.

EDIT (as requested ;) ):
- xrandr documentation page: http://www.x.org/wiki/Projects/XRandR
- an online version of 'man xrandr': http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xrandr/

Comment: Thanks Patkos! please add some links to xrandr references